# Adding additional logic to a lambda function to get the minimum value from a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary with values mapping some object to an integer; e.g. {node: 1, node: 2}.

I want to get the key that corresponds to the minimum value in this dictionary, which I know I can do with:

`min_key = min(my_dict, key=lambda k: my_dict[k])`

**However**, I'd also like to add the constraint that the key is not contained within some other set. Here's the pseudo-code that I wished worked:

`min_key = min(my_dict, key=lambda k: my_dict[k] where k not in my_set)`

Is there a way to write this as a one-liner in python as part of a lambda, or do I now have to explicitly loop through the dictionary and add the logic within the loop like this?

```
min_key, min_value = None, float('inf')
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    if v < min_value and k not in my_set:
        min_key = k
return min_key
```

Comment: That's not a valid dictionary, you can't have duplicate keys.

Comment: A standard trick is to return `math.inf` for the values you want to ignore when taking the minimum.  Likewise use `-math.inf` for finding the maximum. So your example would be `key=lambda k: math.inf if k in my_set else my_dict[k]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `my_dict` with a dictionary comprehension that returns the filtered dictionary.

```
min_key = min({k:v for k, v in my_dict.items() if k not in my_set}, 
                key = lambda k: my_dict[k])
```

Comment: No point building a dict with values, as `min` is going to ignore them.

Comment: You're right, we just need a list of keys.

Comment: Since you posted that answer, I won't bother editing mine.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to @Barmar's answer but you can also use `set.difference` between `my_dict` and `my_set` to filter the relevant dictionary:

```
out = min(set(my_dict).difference(my_set), key = lambda k: my_dict[k])
```

Comment: Putting extra effort into the values that `min` is going to ignore anyway seems wasteful.

Comment: @KellyBundy you're right, that's an excellent point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the minimum over the filtered keys instead of all keys:

```
min_key = min(my_dict.keys() - my_set, key=my_dict.get)
```

(Note I also replaced your `key` function, no need to write your own.)